# How to change dynamically default tab in NavigationUI component on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, uinavigationcontroller, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-graph

In my application, I want to show bottom tabs and when click on these tabs show one `fragment`.
For this I used `BottomNavigationView` and `NavigationUI` component for show fragments

**My XML code:**

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/homePage_fragmentNavHost"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/home_navigator"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/homePage_bottomNavBar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/homePage_toolbar"/>
<!--Bottom menu-->
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/homePage_bottomNavBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_home_navigation"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
        app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationView.Active"
        app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationView"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_bar_colors"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_bar_colors"/>
```

And I write **below codes**, for connect `NavigationUi` and `BottomNavigationView` :

```
private fun setupNavigation() {
    val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.homePage_fragmentNavHost)
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(homePage_bottomNavBar, navController)
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp() = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.homePage_fragmentNavHost).navigateUp()
```

But always show the item 0 for default tab.

I want write condition and check one value and with this value set **default tab** for this `NavigationUi` and `BottomNavigationView`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `graph` you can define the `startDestination`.
Something like:

```
    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.homePage_fragmentNavHost) as NavHostFragment
    val graphInflater = navHostFragment.navController.navInflater
    val navGraph = graphInflater.inflate(R.navigation.home_navigator)
    navGraph.startDestination = R.id.nav_xxxxx
    navController.graph = navGraph
            

    findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.homePage_bottomNavBar)
        .setupWithNavController(navController)
```